# Is there a difference in difficulty between hardcore and softcore?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between Hardcore and Normal heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66173/differences-between-hardcore-and-normal-heroes)

Other than the obvious death restrictions, is there a difference in difficulty level between hardcore and softcore mode? In particular, I've heard that there are higher quality items available to hardcore players. Does this make encounters any easier, keeping in mind that you really, really don't want to die?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66173/differences-between-hardcore-and-normal-heroes, and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68088/what-are-the-advantages-of-hardcore-mode

Answer (score 0):

As per current [wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Hardcore):

A player may create a Hardcore character - the true test of the player's skills.

A Hardcore character is the same as a normal character except for the following:

- When a Hardcore character dies, the game ends and you cannot simply
  reload your last save point because the character is gone forever.
- When a Hardcore character dies, they are not removed from the
  Character Selection Screen, instead remaining there as a robed figure
  (as pictured) to remind players of their loss until the character is
  deleted by the player.
- Only the Items the Character has worn can be looted by other players
  (if the player has allowed this before the character died). In
  effect, the game treats you like a mortal human being rather than the
  semi-immortal non-Hardcore characters, accordingly called Softcore by
  Hardcore players.
- Hardcore characters are displayed in a more aggressive pose in the
  Character Selection Screen, depicting their tense state of play.
- Hardcore characters get different Titles for beating the game.

Other than these, there are no other differences in gameplay terms. Dead hardcore characters will even retain whatever position on the Hardcore Ladder they may have achieved (albeit with their names in gray) until they have been surpassed by enough other players to knock them off of the Ladder. Hardcore mode is regarded by many as a more realistic playing experience.

Comment: I believe that wiki you have linked is for Diablo II. In particular, there are no titles in D3(?). Also, I'm pretty sure that you can't loot other players at all in D3.

Comment: interesting, i'll wait and confirm, but I am pretty sure that there are no other benefits.

Comment: [This wiki entry](http://www.diablowiki.net/Hardcore) is much more recent.  Of note, the body of your character doesn't appear to be lootable, meaning your items on you are all gone.

Comment: ill edit my comment, but atm i get 504 on the link